# Inserting Into Text File Blank

Tags: c

I ask for two simple user inputs, a user and a password, I then insert those into a text file, each followed by a semi colon. The semi colons save and the password saves but the username doesn't save for some odd reason.

For example if I input Joe with password 111222444555 it'll 
display as `;111222444555;` instead of `Joe;111222444555;`

Code:

```
int main()
{
    int Number_Of_Attempts = 3;
    int result = 0;
    char userID[32];
    printf("Please enter your user id\n");

    scanf("%s", &userID);

    char password[12];

    printf("The user has not been found. Please enter your a password\n");


    scanf("%s", &password);


    printf("Username and Password has been saved");
    printf("\n");

    InsertIntoHash(userID, password);

    return 0;
}


void InsertIntoHash(char *userID, char *hash)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("HashTable.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fp, userID);
    fprintf(fp,";");
    fprintf(fp, hash);
    fprintf(fp, ";\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Why not `fprintf(fp, "%s;%s;\n", userId, hash);` ?

Comment: May be, for some reason, you are writing some CR (carriage return) into the file? How long is the file for "Joe;..."?

Comment: You should printf your two variables so that you can see what is being provided to InsertIntoHash.  That will help you isolate where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read in the string using `scanf("%31s", userID);` for the userID and `scanf("%11s", password);` for the password.
What I think causes the problem is, that you declare and define `InsertIntoHash`after the main function, without declaring a prototype at the beginning.
So the code should be the following: (I tested it and it works)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void InsertIntoHash(char *userID, char *hash);

int main() {
    int Number_Of_Attempts = 3;
    int result = 0;
    char userID[32];
    printf("Please enter your user id\n");
    scanf("%31s", userID);
    char password[12];
    printf("The user has not been found. Please enter your a password\n");
    scanf("%11s", password);
    printf("Username and Password has been saved");
    printf("\n");
    InsertIntoHash(userID, password);
    return 0;
}

void InsertIntoHash(char *userID, char *hash) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("HashTable.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fp, userID);
    fprintf(fp,";");
    fprintf(fp, hash);
    fprintf(fp, ";\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I hope I could help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `scanf("%s", &userID);` to `scanf("%s", userID);` as it is already an array which will be passed as a pointer. Same for password.

---

Note the buffer for password is too small: the password is 12 chars and the buffer too so the terminating null character is placed outside the buffer (resulting in Undefined Behavior, as you encounter).

Use `"%11s"` to limit the length read to the size of the buffer, leaving room for the terminating null character.

Comment: After removing & from scanf functions, I still get the same weird result\

Comment: @Master Then share the weird result.

Comment: @AmitKumar, it's in the original post bud.